# Ubuntu 12.04 - syslog showing "SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled"

Tags: filesystem

I have been seeing these random logs in syslog on our production system.
There is no XFS setup.  Fstab only shows local partitions, only EXT3 .
There is nothing in crontabs either.

The only file system related package I have installed is 'nfs-kernel-server' 
Kernel version is  3.2.0-31-generic .

```
kernel: [601730.795990] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
kernel: [601730.798710] SGI XFS Quota Management subsystem
kernel: [601730.828493] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
kernel: [601730.897024] NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
kernel: [601730.964412] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
kernel: [601731.035679] Btrfs loaded
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos on mounted /dev/vda1
10freedos: debug: /dev/vda1 is not a FAT partition: exiting
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx on mounted /dev/vda1
10qnx: debug: /dev/vda1 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx on mounted /dev/vda1
macosx-prober: debug: /dev/vda1 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft on mounted /dev/vda1
20microsoft: debug: /dev/vda1 is not a MS partition: exiting
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility on mounted /dev/vda1
30utility: debug: /dev/vda1 is not a FAT partition: exiting
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb on mounted /dev/vda1
debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd on mounted /dev/vda1
debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix on mounted /dev/vda1
debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku on mounted /dev/vda1
83haiku: debug: /dev/vda1 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90bsd-distro on mounted /dev/vda1
83haikuos-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro on mounted /dev/vda1
os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris on mounted /dev/vda1
os-prober: debug: /dev/vda2: is active swap
```

Why would this randomly show up?
This also spawns multiple "jfsCommit" processes.

Answer (score 4):

These aren't random, they are part of os-prober determining partitions and then installed OSes before the system configures/installs a new kernel. If you have security updates enabled this can happen without you doing anything.